# Russian Chibis suit

Tags: iss, spacesuits, soviet-union

The Russian Chibis suit is operational since 1971 and is used aboard the ISS, are there recent developments in this technology? How effective has it been found in counteracting the tendency of fluids to accumulate in the upper extremities and how often do astronauts typically use this suit?

Comment: As often with Russian spaceflight - it's hard to find in-depth information... Here is link to American authors. According to them, negative pressure suit is effective, endeed. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337660672_Mobile_Lower_Body_Negative_Pressure_Suit_as_an_Integrative_Countermeasure_for_Spaceflight/link/5f357b26a6fdcccc43c5dbcc/download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of the components of the system for preventing the adverse effects
> of microgravity is the Chibis preventive vacuum kit (PVK). This
> prophylactic kit has been used for a long time, but during the flight
> of our expedition ISS-30, a **modified Chibis-M** was delivered to the
> ISS.
>
> Одним из компонентов системы профилактики неблагоприятного воздействия
> микрогравитации является профилактический вакуумный комплект (ПВК)
> «Чибис». Данное профилактическое средство используется давно, но в
> период полета нашей экспедиции МКС-30 на борт МКС был доставлен
> модифицированный «Чибис-М».
>
> The new modification of the Chibis-M PVK differs significantly from
> its predecessor. It has become more autonomous and easy to use. A
> fundamentally new compressor unit has appeared, modern software for
> the training and examination process has been created, a tablet
> computer is included in the kit.
>
> Новая модификация ПВК «Чибис-М» существенно отличается от
> предшественника. Он стал более автономным и удобным в эксплуатации.
> Появился принципиально новый компрессорный блок, создано современное
> програмное обеспечение процесса тренировок и обследований, в состав
> комплекта включен планшетный компьютер.

https://www.roscosmos.ru/3392/